# Cloudfront passes request to incorrect origin if AllViewer origin policy is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I created a cloudfront distribution with the below details:

- Origin1 -> S3Bucket
- Origin2 -> APIGateway endpoint with base /Prod appended
- DefaultBehavior -> `*`, Origin1, CachingEnabled, no Origin Policy
- APIBehavior -> `/api/*`, Origin2, CachingDisabled

With the above setup, I see the desired behavior i.e., all requests to any path starting with `/api/` is redirected to Origin2 and the rest to Origin1. Also the caching policy works fine.

But now I wish to forward headers/query parameters to origin without affecting the caching schema. So for Origin2's behavior (`/api/*`), I added AllViewer Origin policy (Forwards all headers, query requests etc.). But now the `/api/*` calls are redirected to `Prod/api/*` and Origin1 is used instead of Origin2.

This seems so counterintuitive to me, could anyone please enlighten if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you're doing well.

Regarding your inquiry, it seems like the **managed origin request policy** `AllViewer` is the culprit. If you use `AllViewer` policy, it forwards the `host` header to your origin. Please refer to the response below:

Let's say your configuration is like:

- `DefaultBehavior (*)` -> Origin1(S3Bucket)
- `APIBehavior (/api/*)` -> Origin2(APIG/w endpoint with base `/Prod` appended)

The request flow would be:

1. example.com/api/getdata --(Host: example.com)--> CloudFront

> Match the `APIBehavior (/api/*)` path behavior, CloudFront append the path and forward the request.

2. CloudFront --(Host: example.com)--> example.com/Prod/api/getdata

> example.com is a custom domain of your CloudFront distribution; it will go back to you CloudFront distribution again.

3. example.com/Prod/api/getdata --(Redirect)--> CloudFront

> Match the `DefaultBehavior (*)`, CloudFront use `Origin1(S3Bucket)`

4. CloudFront --(Forward request`/Prod/api/getdata`)--> `Origin1(S3Bucket)`

To fix it, I'll suggest you should create a new origin request policy which forwards the necessary headers and query strings only.

Note:
If you make you origin to service like S3 or APIG/w, please don't forward the `host` header. It will cause some unexpected behaviors.

I hope this information has been helpful
Feel free let me know if you have any question

Comment: Thank you @Richard02110 for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score -2):

I am facing the same issue.  My problem is that the only header I need to have forwarded to the API is the Authorization header, and there are special rules in CloudFront preventing the Authorization header from being forwarded to the target unless all headers are forwarded.  I also cannot add the Authorization header to the cache key if the cache is set to not cache anything.

If you switch to use the 'Legacy Cache Settings' and include the desired headers etc and then set the TTL to 0 it seems to act as expected.